# Syntax Issue in Razor code using Vb.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working with my first MVC3, vb.net project and am having a problem with the follow code

```
@code
' builds standard list of attributes
   Dim s1 = SharedAttributeBuilder.BuildAttributes(Me) 
End Code
@Html.TextAreaFor(Model >= Model, 2, 30, @s1)
```

My problem is with the @s1 on the last line.  When I build, I'm getting an "expression expected" error message. I'm somewhat confused as this last line runs fine in other c# projects.
I've tried @(s1) and doesn't work.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

---

**EDIT**  One of my co-workers solved it for me.  I have to use vb syntax for lamdas.  Duh on my part.  Working line looks like

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(Function(Model) Model, 2, 30, s1)
```

Answer (score 0):

tom,

doesn't:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.someproperty, 2, 30, s1)
```

work (i.e. replacing `@s1` with plain old `s1`)??

Certainly in c# this would work as expected (notice the lower-case `model` plus associated property, plus `=>` rather than `>=`).

Comment: It doesn't work.  I now get an overload resolution error on the TextAreaFor.

Comment: ok, unfortunately not sure of the differences in the vb razor syntax as the above actually works as expected in a quick test project in c#

Comment: That is my frustration.  This code works fine in my c# projects.

Comment: feeling your obvious pain - would make any (cough) suggestions :)